# What TTL circuit should I use for an SRAM cell

Tags: digital-logic, homebrew-cpu

I am trying to build a 16 byte RAM module with only bjt transistors and resistors. And I am looking for a suitable circuit for a memory cell.
From what I have understood there are two paths I can take:

1. Make a D-latch for every cell which seems to use a lot of transistors.
2. Smaller systems that require only 4,6 or 8 transistors.
   I want to use option two but all schematics I have found are for MOSFETs.
   Will they work for BJTs too?
   [image: Type of circuit I want]
   If not could someone please provide the most suitable synchronous memory cell schematic made from NPN BJTs.
   Thank you

Comment: Some details here https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/132984/TI/SN7489.html on page 2

Comment: @Uwe But what I want to know is how each of those cells are built.

Comment: dig up some schematics for late 50's computers like the IBM 1401 and CDC6600. That will show you how it was done and you know it will be the minimum required as transistors were expensive back then.

Comment: How are we supposed to answer "Will they work for BJTs too?" without knowing what "they" are? Why not show a circuit you like, and ask if it can be made with BJTs.

Comment: @user253751 Done.

Comment: The upper MOSFETs in this circuit are behaving as resistors.

Comment: @user253751 Oh but then isn't that just a SR-latch? Not really suitable for a memory cell on its own. And if we add the necessary logic to make it a D-latch that's option one.

Comment: @joupy An SR-latch **is** the core of any memory cell I'm aware of.

Answer (score 1):

This is total speculation, but I think that a memory cell made with 4 NPN transistors and 6 resistors should be workable, as long as the transistors work reasonably well in "reverse active" mode for reading the cell. But I don't think you can avoid using some PNP transistors in the word line drivers and in the read sense amplifiers. Here's a schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRPUWW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The resistor values are total guesses at this point. Just think of them as "relatively large" and "relatively small" for the purpose of illustration. Simulation and/or experimentation will be required to find workable values. It will be tricky to balance getting it to work while also considering power consumption and timing performance.

To write to the cell, turn on **one** of the "Write Driver" transistors, then pulse the Word Line high, which will turn on one of Q3 or Q4 and force Q1 and Q2 into the correct state. For example, if Q6 is on, then when Q4 switches on, its collector will be pulled low enough to cut off Q1, which in turn will switch on Q2.

To read the cell turn off **both** Write Drivers, then pulse the Word Line high. If Q2 is on, then Q4 will be driven into its "reverse active" mode, and it should pull the Bit Line on the left low, while the /Bit Line on the right is not pulled down at all. The Read Sense Amplifier, a simple differential pair at the bottom center, should be able to detect this difference and turn it into a logic-level data output.

To increase the word width, stack additional cells horizontally, each with its own set of bit lines, write drivers and sense amplifier, but sharing the word line. To increase the number of words, stack additional cells vertically, each with its own word line, but sharing the bit lines.

Answer (score 0):

First, note that TTL does not mean “some transistorized logic”. It’s a very specific logic family that is amenable to mass manufacture on ICs and not most sensible for discrete implementations, since many core TTL primitives are plainly missing from the discrete world. You are not going to find transistors with multiple emitters or collectors that you can just stick into the circuit, as TTL would need.

So your question doesn’t really have much to do with TTL, but rather with bipolar transistors.

For 16 bytes, even 8 transistors per bit is nothing, since the rest of your CPU will use orders of magnitude more transistors anyway. So not a problem to worry about. You can redo that SRAM later if you really want to cut down on the transistor count. The external multiplexing to access the cells will use about as many transistors as the cells for such a small number of bits. These days you’ll be putting it all on a PCB since that will be faster to assemble than hand wiring stuff, and copy-pasting the same circuit 128 or 256 times is no big deal.

Stuff that’s easy to do in discrete components is often impossible on a chip - and vice versa. So, since you’re making discrete memory, you can use small capacitors for storage and transistors for column drivers and sense amplifiers. If you want to have the fewest transistors, you’ll need DRAM with self-refresh that can acts as SRAM would given amenable external timing. Any capacitors you use for this will have orders of magnitude more capacitance than any bipolar DRAM chips had, and will retain their contents for minutes if not hours without refresh. You’ll want more than 16 bytes though to get the benefits of DRAM cells - as you’ll need to amortize all the “non storage” interface circuitry, refresh counter, etc.

Comment: The [ABC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atanasoff%E2%80%93Berry_computer) had a drum full of capacitors, where each row made mechanical contact with the write/read/refresh circuitry as it rotated.